# How to identify the time delays of each feature in a multi-variable time series prediction model

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, feature-selection

I'm trying to build a time-series forecasting model that looks like the following:

#### Model Inputs:

x1(t), x1(t-1), x1(t-2), ..., x1(t-12)

x2(t), x2(t-1), x2(t-2), ..., x2(t-12)

y(t), y(t-1), y(t-2), ..., y(t-12)

#### Model Outputs:

y(t+1)

#### Where:

- x1, x2: features
- y: label
- t-1, t-2, ..., t-12: time-steps

x1, x2, and y are continuous time-series data.

#### Here's my question:

This is a "feature selection" question. I don't want to put all the time-steps into the model. Instead, I want to select the most important time-step among x1, x2, and y.

For example, given feature x1, assume (t-2) is the most important time-step to predict y(t+1), then x1(t-2) is selected and the other time-steps are dropped. So as x2 and y.

The final model would looks like this:

y(t+1) = f(y(t), x1(t-2), x2(t-6))

I know reduce the number of features will decrease model performance. However, it's OK in my case because it's more valuable for me to find out the time delay among these features .

Is there any method to identify (t-2) is a significant time-step to make prediction of y(t+1)? Such as machine learning, statistics, etc.

Comment: I would answer with the link feature selection from `sklearn` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html), but I'm not sure in your case, because you have only one class. Since I'm not pretty sure about this topic, I would advise you to take a look in PCA http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: Which regression model uses for to predict t + 1? Regression Trees and Random Forests? , Linear and Polynomial Regression ?, Neural Networks?

Comment: @LorranSutter Thanks, I read the doc from scikit-learn, it says decision tree like method has feature_importances_ attribute which may be useful. We can also apply linear model such as linear regression with L1 penalty (Lasso) penalize unimportant features with exactly zero weight.

Comment: @Hendouz Maybe linear model or decision tree like model can select features. I don't think neural network can select features because the weights in the network are hard to interpret.